# Angular constant : config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, constants

I'm working on an Angular app and I'd like to create a config file. From what I read, I should use angular constant.

So I tried to create my constant. From what I read ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046743/how-to-use-constant-module-in-angular), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876439/configuration-file-in-angularjs) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159867/angular-constant-best-practice) + [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module)), it seems quiet easy.

Here is my file :

```
 angular.module('app')

     .constant('config', {

         routers : {

             Commandes: 'some_data',
             Prestations: 'some_data',
             Interventions: 'some_data'
        },

         serverPath : 'some_data'
 });
```

As I read it's possible to inject it in a service, I tried to use it in a factory and to display it :

```
 app.factory('myFactory', [function(config) { 

      console.log('config : '+config);
      return // something;
}]);
```

But the config appears "undefined" (no error here, just `console.log` things).

It seems that I'm not gettong it, but what the hell did I miss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the constant from the factory service you have to use the whole path as you defined in your config file.

In your example:

```
config.serverPath
config.routers.Commandes
// etc...
```

Another thing is that you need to define the constants as dependencies inside the square brackets:

```
app.factory('myFactory', ['config', function(config) { 

      console.log('config : '+config);
      return // something;
}]);
```

Comment: I tried to use 'config' in the factory because I was getting an error when using 'config.serverPath', as I forgot to define the constant as a dependecy. Thanks a lot man !